# How to DELETE Records from Target Database in SSIS

Tags: ssis

Same database exist on  two servers. I will call them Source and Destination for simplicity here. I need to compare records and delete those only exist in target but not in Source. I can't use Execute SQL as both databases exist on different Servers and there is no link between them. Can anyone propose a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could populate a table on the target with the IDs from the source table. Then use an Execute SQL task on the Destination database to delete rows from target table that do not exist in the table you populated. Eg, something like:

```
DELETE FROM TargetTable
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TableIDsFromDestination)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create an Staging base in the Destination server where you are going to copy the information without look for references, after that you can do the compare directly in the same server.

I hope it helps.